# Roslyn Workspace API : Emit each Project inside Solution to dll

Tags: roslyn

I started to wonder how to emit C# Projects using Workspace API and Compiler API from Rolsyn.

This what I get so far:

```
var msBuild = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();

var sln = msBuild.OpenSolutionAsync
    (@"D:\User\Documents\visual studio 14\Projects\ConsoleApplicationWorkspaces"
    +@"\ConsoleApplicationWorkspaces.sln").Result;

foreach (var item in sln.Projects)
{
    EmitProject(item);
}


public static async void EmitProject(Project proj)
{
   var c = await proj.GetCompilationAsync();

   var options = new CSharpCompilationOptions
    (OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary);

   c = c.WithOptions(options);

   c = c.AddReferences(proj.MetadataReferences);

   var result = c.Emit("my" + proj.Name + ".dll");

   Console.WriteLine(r.Success);
}
```

This code don't work. 
According to diagnostic info I didn't add references like "System.Runtime","System.Linq".

Using Workspace API I can get references I need but I guess I still I am adding them wrong.

Comment: Side note: Don't write `async void`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to change the options or references that come back from `Project.GetCompilationAsync`.  You should just be able to call `Emit` directly.

Note that you should emit the projects in topological sort order, which you can get from `Solution.GetProjectDependencyService`.

Comment: Can you give more details about "You should just be able to call Emit directly.". This isn't working for me.

Comment: Why is it necessary to do it in topological sort order? Project references will exist between the projects -- we won't be depending upon on-disk binaries for intermediate projects.

Comment: Ah, good point, though doing topological order would give you diagnostics in a reasonable order.

Comment: Kevin you answer from another question resolved this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27997630/roslyn-workspace-api-emiting-wpf-and-silverlight-projects